Time complexity of solving systems of equations with a sparse structure.
I have a following systems of equations with $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}, c\in \mathbb{R}^{m}, a \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
B^{T} & \mathrm{diag}[c] \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x  \\ y
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
a  \\ b
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
I know that solving this equations costs $\mathcal{O}((n+m)^{3})$. Let us call this is strategy 1.
Now, Let me explain strategy 2. Using the sparse structure of the (2,2) block of the coefficient matrix, $y$ is solved easily by
$$
y = c^{-1}\odot b -B^{T}x,
$$
where $\odot$ is a element-wise multiplication. Plugging this into the first equation, we get
$$
Ax+B(c^{-1}\odot b-B^{T}x) =a \Leftrightarrow (A-BB^{T})x = - B(c^{-1}\odot b).
$$
Inverting the matrix on the left-hand side costs $\mathcal{O}(n^{3})$, and computing the right hand side costs $\mathcal{O}(nm)$ (because of the matrix-vector multiplication). Therefore, this strategy costs $\mathcal{O}(n^{3}+nm)$.
Is my analysis correct?

$c^{-1}$: $m$; $c^{-1}\odot b$: $m^2$; $B^{\top}x$: $mn^2$; $B(c^{-1}\odot b)$: $n\times m^2$

Sorry, but why $c^{-1} \odot b$ costs $m^{2}$? They are $m$ vectors. Isn't multiplying each $m$ elements amounts to $\mathcal{O}(n)$?

Sorry again, I meant $\mathcal{O}(m)$ in the last complexity.
